# add a repeatable autopopulate node title select list to custom block

Tags: forms

I'm going to develop a new block that user can select 4(or more) node with 4(or more) autopopulate node selection list but i couldn't find any documentation or tutorial on how to build those select list.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [form select options](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_select_options/7)

put the list of your nodes in to an array and pass them into the form function

```
function mylist_form($form, &$form_state, $args) {
$mylist = array();
foreach ($args as $node){
$mylist[$node->nid]= $node->title;
}

$form['mylist'] = array(
  '#weight' => '1',
  '#key_type' => 'associative',
  '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $mylist,
  '#title' => 'Select nodes',
);
 return $form;
}
```

after in the block view function you can render the form

```
$mylistform = drupal_get_form('mylist_form' , $nodes );
```